# double quoted variable inside single quoted sql query variable

Tags: php, sql, odbc

```
'...where T4."firstName"!=\'ERD\''
```

*I am sure you know but: `''\'ERD\''` means "ERD"  inside single quotation marks.
This is a part of sql query but I want to use a variable instead of ERD. Having trouble with double and single quotation marks. How should I write the variable?

An option to prevent SQL injection is appreciated. I am using ODBC.

Comment: With ODBC, you probably want to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Take advantage of the prepared statements and parameter binding, and you won't have to worry about quoting issues at all.

Comment: I can't use PDO because PHP 8.2 doesn't have a PDO driver :( @aynber

Comment: Yes it does. PHP did not get rid of the PDO driver. You may need to build it in, however. https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php

Comment: will php_sqlsr_81 work, because it is the latest one as i can see @aynber

Comment: I believe that's for Microsoft SQL Server. I don't know if it will work for ODBC

Comment: @aynber Sorry, I was confused odbc_prepare didn't help about quoting. I'll try PDO.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest concatenating it:

```
"SELECT * from table1 where firstName = '" . $ERD . "'";
```

Comment: would $ERD be "ERD" or 'ERD' tried both but got nothing...

Comment: '.....=1 and T4."firstName"!='.$ERD.''' this is how I did thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).